# Run ADX script on cluster scope with bicep

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-explorer, azure-bicep

I use Azure Devops pipelines. You can run a script on the database level with Bicep, that is listed clearly in the documents. But I want to run a script on cluster level to update the workload_group policy to increase the allowed concurrent queries. But when running the query as part of the bicep deployment (on the [database script property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.kusto/clusters/databases/scripts?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)) to alter this it results in the following error:
`Reason: Not a database-scope command`

How can I run this query (that should indeed be run on a cluster level) as part of the bicep deployment? I use the following query, that does work when running it in the query window in Azure Portal.

````
.create-or-alter workload_group ['default'] ```
   <<workgroupConfig>>
```.
````

I also know there are tasks for Azure Devops for running scripts against the database, but I would not like to use those since data explorer is in a private network and not accessible publicly.

Comment: I'm running into something similar.  Have you been able to find a solution for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, for now we just don't change the amount of allowed concurrent queries. It is possible with adding a (powershell) script in your pipeline after the bicep deployment I suppose, but I have not tried this yet.

Comment: I think it should be possible using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/devops

Comment: @FrederikGheysels that is true. It will in the background run scripts against Azure (like with powershell), and that will not work when you have a locked down ADX cluster with firewall rules.